# Upload Document with MTOM Webservice in .net

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, wsdl, mtom

I have to upload documents trough an web service. The web service supports MTOM. Because the documents can be really big i want to upload the Document within a stream.
The problem is Visual Studio deserailizes the property for the data as byte array (byte[]). So I have to load the whole document into Memory before i upload it.

How is it possible to deserialice the wsdl with a Stream Property for the data?
If it is not possible how has the wsdl look like for .net to deserialice it correct?

WSDL looks like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://gen.ws.abcd.com" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
     xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/"
     xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" targetNamespace="http://gen.ws.abcd.com">
    <wsdl:documentation>
  TestWService
    </wsdl:documentation>
    <wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Message" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Message">
            <xs:simpleType name="StreamBody">
                <xs:restriction base="xs:base64Binary"/>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:schema>
        <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
            <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Message"/>
            <xs:element name="MTomDataType">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element xmlns:q1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Message" name="Data" type="q1:StreamBody"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="StringValue" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:schema>
        <xsd:schema xmlns="http://gen.ws.abcd.com" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://gen.ws.abcd.com">
            <xsd:complexType name="TImportDocumentImport">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="master_filename" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="temporary_filename" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="doc_number" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="doc_type_long" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="doc_type_short" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="var_number" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="doc_status" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="user" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="doc_filename" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="doc_extension" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="doc_directory" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="doc_text_4" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="doc_text_3" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="doc_text_2" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="doc_text_1" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="holdfile_user" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="holdfile_group" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="holdfile_date" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="holdfile_notice" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="holdfile_date_remember" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="holdfile_date_acknowledge_until" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="book_attribute" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="reserved_doc_id_header" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="reserved_doc_id_suffix" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="transfer_synchron" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="reject_duplicates" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="import_hash" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="asynchronous" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="signatures_required" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="batch_alteration_number" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="color_code" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="check_hash" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="import_date" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="iso" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="doc_fields" type="TDocFields" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:complexType name="TImportDocumentExport">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="doc_id" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="time_stamp" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="transfer_error" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="field_no_with_error" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:element name="ImportDocumentRequest">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:complexContent>
                        <xsd:extension base="TTestRequest">
                            <xsd:sequence>
                                <xsd:element name="import" type="TImportDocumentImport" />
                                <xsd:element name="bytes" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:base64Binary" xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime" xmime:expectedContentTypes="application/octet-stream" />
                            </xsd:sequence>
                        </xsd:extension>
                    </xsd:complexContent>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="ImportDocumentResponse">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:complexContent>
                        <xsd:extension base="TTestResponse">
                            <xsd:sequence>
                                <xsd:element name="export" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="TImportDocumentExport" /> 
                            </xsd:sequence>
                        </xsd:extension>
                    </xsd:complexContent>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="ImportDocumentRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="in" element="tns:ImportDocumentRequest"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="ImportDocumentResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="out" element="tns:ImportDocumentResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="TestWServicePortType">
        <wsdl:operation name="ImportDocument">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:ImportDocumentRequest" wsaw:Action="ws.abcd.com/ImportDocument"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:ImportDocumentResponse" wsaw:Action="ws.abcd.com/TestWS/ImportDocumentResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>


    <wsdl:binding name="TestWSbinding" type="tns:TestWServicePortType">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>

        <wsdl:operation name="ImportDocument">
            <soap:operation soapAction="ws.abcd.com/ImportDocument" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="TestWService">
        <wsdl:port name="TestWSPort" binding="tns:TestWSbinding">
            <soap:address location="http://Testserver:8081/ws22/services/TestWServiceGen"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

The Property to deserialize as Stream is in the following line:

```
<xsd:element name="bytes" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:base64Binary" xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime" xmime:expectedContentTypes="application/octet-stream" />
```